# Replacing values in matrix python

Tags: python-2.7

How can one replace values of elements in a (n*n) matrix which are greater than one with 0 s?
I have tried using matrix[matrix>=1]=0 but it is not working. 
This is the code.

```
def stationarydist(self):
        q,Q= self.q,self.Q,
        mat=np.empty([Q+1, Q+1])
        for i in range(Q+1):
            if i<=q:
                mat[i,0]=(1/2)**Q
                for z in range(Q):
                    mat[i,z+1]=(1/2)**(Q-z)
            else:
               mat[i,0]=(1/2)**i
               for j in range(Q):
                   mat[i,j+1]=(1/2)**(i-j)

                   mat[mat>=1]=0
```

It is giving the following error.

```
mat[i,j+1]=(1/2)**(i-j)
ZeroDivisionError: 0.0 cannot be raised to a negative power
```

the idea was to replace all values where i-j<0 with zeroes

Comment: Please show the code you have used more fully. When you say not working what exactly is not working? Are you getting an error or incorrect output?

Comment: You should edit your question to put the code in there. Also use code tags to make the format clearer